# Can a file end with a 0x80 char?

Tags: c++, c, padding, blowfish

I'm implementing my own version of blowfish encoder/decoder. I use a standard padding of 0x80 if necessary.

My question is if I need to add a padding chars even if I don't need it, because in the case of a file that ends naturally with 0x80, in the deconding part I will remove this character, but in this case it is a wrong action, since te 0x80 is part of the file itself.

This of course can be solved by adding a final char even if the total number of characters is a multiple of the encoding block (64bit in this case). I can implement this countermeasure, but first I'd prefer to know if I really need it.

Natural consequence is thinking if this type of char is chosen because never happens in a file (so the wrong situation above never happens), but I'm not sure at all.

Thanks! and sorry for the dummy question..

Comment: Your question may be operating system (and file system) specific. On Linux and most other Posix OSes (with their native filesystem) a file can contain any sequence of any bytes. So it could end with `0x80`

Comment: The padding is part of the format of your input/output data. There can't be any confusion between data that's part of what you feed to your decoder or output from your encoder and other data that might also be in the same file (and that's one of the reasons for the use of padding - so e.g. each block can be of a known length.)

Comment: This question is NOT OS-specific, as least as to what bytes can occur in a file. A binary file (and you always want to be using binary files) can contain any bytes. It's possible that a non-POSIX-conforming OS can pad the end of a binary file with zero bytes, which would make the question nontrivial, but not that 0x80 could be forbidden.

Comment: You could manually add padding; if the file ends with a `0x80` char, pad with some other char. If no padding was required, add one block filled with your chosen padding char. This way, the last character tells you your choice of padding character. So to unpad, read the last character (from decrypted content of course) and trim these characters. This way you will never trim a character which has been part of the original content. *Edit: oh I just saw that you had pretty much this idea. But make sure to choose a different character if the file ends with `0x80`.*

Comment: Thankyou all. I see if adding a final 8 bytes will create some disaster in my synchronisation of the algorithm. Of course the padding can still be of 0x80 because I stop at the first occurrence of this char when I check it.

Answer (score 4):

On Linux and other filesystem a file can contain any sequence of any bytes. So ideally you can not depended on any particular byte to decide file end. (Although EOF is there..!!)

What i am suggesting is the Most file formats are using.

You can have specific 4-5 magic bytes Header for your file format. and followed by you can have size of rest of bytes. So after some bytes your last byte would be there.

**Edit:**

In above suggestion In encoder you need to update size of file after adding any new data in files.

If you do not want that then you can encode your data in perticular chunk of data and then encode them packet by packet. Your file will be number of some packet. such things are used in NAL units

Answer (score 3):

Blowfish is a block cipher. It always takes 64 bit input and outputs 64 bit output. If you want to encrypt a stream that is not a multiple of 64 bit long you will need to add some padding bytes. When you decrypt the encrypted stream you always get a multiple of 64 bit. But you have no information if the encrypted stream contained 'real' data or padding bytes. You need to keep track of that yourself. A simple approach would be to store the set of 'data length' and 'encrypted stream'. Another approach would be to prepend the clear text stream with a data length value, for example a 64 bit unsigned integer. Then after decrypting the encrypted stream you will have that length as the first value and then you know how many bytes of the last block are real data and how many are just padding.

And regarding your question about what bytes can be at the end of a file: any. You can have files with arbitrary content. Each byte in the file can be of any value, there is no restriction.

Answer (score 1):

Regular binary file can contain any bytes sequence, so file can end with 0x80, with NULL or any other.

If you are talking about some specific standard, so it depends.. However I think that there is no such file type that could not contain some specific character in the end, I know about file types that ignores as many last characters as not needed (because header determines size) so you should do so, but never heard about illegal file data (except cracked).

---

So as mentioned use header, reserve for example 8 bytes that determines size. That is easy solution.

---

Also, before asking such question, you should ask yourself, why file should end with some special character?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is Yes. On every operating system in current use, a file can end with any possible sequence of bytes. In fact, you should generate such a file to test your implementation.

In the general case you cannot recognise trailing padding characters or remove them reliably without knowing the length of the file. Therefore encoding the length of the file must be part of your cryptographic protocol.

Simply put the length of the file at the beginning and encrypt the whole thing, including any padding bytes you like (random is probably best). Once unencrypted you will have the file length to tell you where to truncate.